# Angular 8 - Dificuldade ao recuperar headers

Tags: java, angular-8

Salve galera, estou tentando pegar o header do retorno de minha requisição http para efetuar o login.
No header desta Response contem o a key 'Authorization', porém com o código a seguir não estou conseguindo pegar o valor:

```
login(username, password) {
    return this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>(`${environment.apiUrl}authenticate`, {},
        {
            observe: 'response',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'user': username,
                'key': password
            }
        })
        .pipe(tap(resp=> {
            console.log(resp.headers);
            console.log(resp.headers.get('Authorization'));
            console.log(resp.body);
            return resp.body;
        }));
}
```

Utilizando o Postman o retorno esperado acontece.
O que poderia ser, estou fazendo algo errado?

Vale uma observação de que o meu código do backend é em Java e se eu adicionar alguma informação no "body", o "console.log(resp.body);" Exibe corretamente, porém o header continua sem a informação.

```
@POST
public Response login(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    Autenticator autenticator = Autenticator.getInstance();

    String user = headers.getHeaderString(Headers.USER);
    String key = headers.getHeaderString(Headers.KEY);
    UsuarioTO to = autenticator.login(user, key);
    return Response.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, Headers.BEARER + " " + to.token).build();
}
```

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente adicionar o seguinte [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) na resposta. Por padrão ele não é exposto.

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
```

Exemplo:

```
@POST
public Response login(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    Autenticator autenticator = Autenticator.getInstance();

    String user = headers.getHeaderString(Headers.USER);
    String key = headers.getHeaderString(Headers.KEY);
    UsuarioTO to = autenticator.login(user, key);
    return Response.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, Headers.BEARER + " " + to.token).header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization").build();
}
```

Comment: Ola, vou testar hoje a noite e dou uma resposta sobre. Mas desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Então rapaz, é isso ai mesmo, verifiquei meu filtro CORS e eu, realmente, não tinha esse header adicionado, também, não o conhecia! Obrigado.